# How to use TBB with gcc on OSX?

Tags: macos, gcc, parallel-processing, installation, tbb

How to install Intel Threading Building Blocks on OSX 10.9, so it can be used with gcc?

I tried to do what usually works for me on Linux:

1. Download the source.
2. install using `make`.
3. Specify `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPATH`.
4. Use like

   ```
   g++ mycode.cpp -O3 -o mycode -ltbb
   ```

result:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libtbb.dylib
  Referenced from: /blabla/mycode
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Try specifying DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OSX, it is DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 3):

You can install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install tbb
```

That takes care of the lib paths, so you only have to add `-ltbb` to the linker flags.